# Spring Boot Starter Tomcat 2.3.9 javax/annotation inconsistency

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot Starter Tomcat 2.3.9.RELEASE
has dependencies

```
jakarta.annotation » jakarta.annotation-api 1.3.5
```

and

```
org.apache.tomcat.embed » tomcat-embed-core 9.0.43
```

If we run maven enforcer plugin with **BanDuplicateClasses** rule
there is an error

```
<banDuplicateClasses>
   <findAllDuplicates>true</findAllDuplicates>
   <ignoreWhenIdentical>true</ignoreWhenIdentical>
</banDuplicateClasses>
```

> [WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanDuplicateClasses failed with
> message: Duplicate classes found:
>
> Found in:
> jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
> org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:9.0.43:compile   Duplicate classes:
> javax/annotation/PreDestroy.class
> javax/annotation/Resource$AuthenticationType.class
> javax/annotation/Generated.class
> javax/annotation/security/DeclareRoles.class
> javax/annotation/Priority.class
> javax/annotation/Resource.class
> javax/annotation/security/DenyAll.class
> javax/annotation/security/RunAs.class
> javax/annotation/security/PermitAll.class
> javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.class
> javax/annotation/Resources.class
> javax/annotation/PostConstruct.class
> javax/annotation/sql/DataSourceDefinition.class

If to update jakarta.annotation-api to 2.0.0 the error disappears.
But it looks like versions inconsistency of **spring-boot-dependencies** bom file